# Setting product slider width on window resize along with CSS media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a working product slider that now I'm trying to reduce width for smaller viewport
which isn't going so well.

The code starts with adding up the width of each product item when document is loaded
and slide happens when buttons are clicked.

My problem is that when viewport gets smaller, every product item will become narrower (handled with CSS media query) and now with script, it needs to re-calculate the new width specified in the media query when browser window gets resized.

I tried to refactor into a function or a variable and pass it in `resize()`
but no luck seeing the total with calculated with resize event.
I should separate event and function but then I face some variable scope issue.

Please see [My JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/fkayk7g6/27/)

I understand this is probably no use for normal users but I want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use match media

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) { 
//code for window less than 480px

}
else
{ 
}
```

[Match Media Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)